# what should I look into in order to make object A loop on object B's surface?

Tags: modeling

I want to duplicate this holder around the surface of this main cylinder (and facing front for each one of them)
I learned to use array and add a empty arrow to manage some circle arranged chair legs but in this case these holders has a front side

Which tool should I look into?
[image]

Comment: Why is the "front side" a problem? That's not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an *Array* modifier but you can also simply make the object rotate around an axis:

Put the 3D cursor at the center of the cylinder with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, select the 3D cursor in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel:

[image]

Select the holder, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>60</kbd> (or any rotation degree), then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the operation as many times as needed (6 times if the rotation was 60°):

[image]

Comment: right i should've thought about it! thanks a lot!!)